# In F#, an 'is X' operator for case identifiers?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

Let's say I have the following discriminated union and value:

```
type DisUnion = 
    | One of string
    | Two of string
    | Three of string * string

let myVal = One("One")
```

I know I can use pattern matching to determine which case `myVal` belongs to, like this:

```
let whatever (x : DisUnion) = match x with
    | One(str) -> "It was One"
    | Two(str) - > "It was two"
    | Three(str, str) -> "It was three"
```

But I can't seem to find an operator or method that allows me to determine the case identifier *without* pattern matching, like:

```
let isOne (x : DisUnion) = x :? One //I thought this would work, but it doesn't.
```

How would I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need this? Isn't `x` of type `DisUnion` in any time?

Comment: I'm not trying to check if `x : DisUnion`. I'm trying to check if `x is One`.

Comment: @Greg you may consider re-wording your question. You've asked for a solution _without_ pattern matching, but actually chosen an answer _with_ one.

Comment: That's what I was *looking for* yeah, but I was provided with a suitable answer, especially given that such an operator may not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let isOne = function One(_) -> true | _ -> false
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
let isOne x = match x with One(_) -> true | _ -> false
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you say a few words about what's going on?

Comment: An individual case is not a type, so you can't use the `:?` operator on it. The 'type' is `DisUnion`, and if you want to check for a particular case, you need to do a pattern match. The answer here uses the shorthand form for a pattern match function where the argument need not be specified. I've edited the answer to show the equivalent 'full' version.

Comment: @GregRos - F# provides the `function` form as a shorthand for `let func x = match x with` when `func` has only one argument. As far as I know there is no built-in operator to match one case of a discriminated union so this is the shortest approach.

Comment: I see. Thanks guys. As you may imagine, all this F# business is very confusing to a backwards C#/imperative programming hippie such as myself.

Comment: FWIW the parentheses are superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such operator built into F#, but there are a couple different approaches to achieving your goal.

A novel approach, which loses type checking and thus wouldn't typically be used, is via reflection. We note that discriminant unions are implement by the F# compiler using, in your example, `DisUnion` as a base class and each of the union cases, `One`, `Tow`, and `Three` as subclasses of `DisUnion`. Thus we can implement the following operator:

```
let (=?) duInstance caseName = 
    let duInstanceTy = duInstance.GetType()
    duInstanceTy.Name = caseName
```

and use it like so:

```
> One("hi") =? "One";;
val it : bool = true
> One("hi") =? "Two";;
val it : bool = false
> One("hi") =? "NotValid";;
val it : bool = false
```

More typical, however, would be to implement a set of static members on `DisUnion` to do the job in a statically type-checked way. It's a bit verbose to implement, but it's a one time cost since using the static members is nice.

```
type DisUnion = 
    | One of string
    | Two of string
    | Three of string * string
    static member isOne x =
        match x with
        | One _ -> true
        | _ -> false
    static member isTwo x =
        match x with
        | Two _ -> true
        | _ -> false
    static member isThree x =
        match x with
        | Three _ -> true
        | _ -> false
```

and use it like so:

```
> DisUnion.isOne (One("hi"));;
val it : bool = true
> DisUnion.isOne (Two("hi"));;
val it : bool = false
> DisUnion.isOne (NotValid("hi"));;

  DisUnion.isOne (NotValid("hi"));;
  ----------------^^^^^^^^

C:\stdin(5,17): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'NotValid' is not defined
```